# How can I get the default value for a type?

Tags: haskell, types, default-value

I am trying to build the graph ADT in Haskell.
I don't know how to get the default value for a generic type.

```
type Node = Int
type Element a = (Node, a, [Int]) --Node: ID; a: generic value; [Int]: adjancent nodes' IDs
type Graph a = [Element a]
insNode :: Graph a -> Node -> Graph a
insNode g n = g ++ [(n,?,[])]
```

What do I have to write in place of ? in order to get the default value for type a?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. There's no way to magically create an value of any type.

There's `undefined :: a`, but if ever evaluated this will crash your program. Instead, I'd suggest either

```
type Element a = (Node, Maybe a, [Int]) -- It's optional to have a value
```

or

```
insNode :: a -> Node -> Graph a -> Graph a
-- Optional idea, use `Data.Default` to ease the typing burden
defInsNode :: Def a => Node -> Graph a -> Graph a
defInsNode = insNode def
```

With the first option you can just stick `Nothing` in there (which is really what you have), or with the second option you just require the user to provide a value.

Finally a style note, instead of synonyms for tuples, I'd suggest using

```
type Node = Int
data Element a = Element { node :: Node
                         , val  :: Maybe a
                         , edges :: [Node]}
               deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now you construct these `Elements` with `Element node val edges` and can pattern match in much the same way. Tuples of more than 2 elements are usually the wrong way to go.

Comment: Perhaps a mention of `mempty :: Monoid a => a` should be made? It may look like a fit, but I'm of the opinion that's an easy trap to fall into (i.e. `mempty` is only really useful and meaningful with `mappend`, too), something to warn about.

Comment: @LucDanton Yeah, `Data.Default` is explicitly defined for these cases and `Monoid` well, isn't.

Comment: Many thanks, I have just started studying Haskell!
_Maybe_ is a very good idea for my purpose and for what I've studied so far.
How can I access members of Element using your definition?

Comment: @ShadowTemplate What I'm using is called a [record](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax). You could access a value using `val`. So `val someElement` will give you the `a` inside it.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.5.3

It defines a typeclass called Default, and has some defined default values for most basic types in Haskell.

Comment: @ShadowTemplate It's a library that has a typeclass with a single function `def :: a`, it's meant to be used as the default of something. If you don't know what a typeclass is don't woryy about it